# Complete missing time series data with subgroups

Tags: python, r, missing-data

I have the following dataset:

Create df in Python:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['04-01','04-02','04-02','04-03','04-05']['Red','Blue', 'Yellow','Red', 'Blue'], [1,2,1,1,2], [10,20,10,10,20]]).T
df.columns = ['date','color','quant','revenue']
```

Or in R:

```
date = c('04-01','04-02','04-02','04-03','04-05')
color = c('Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow','Red', 'Blue')
quant = c(1,2,1,1,2)
revenue = c(10,20,10,10,20)
df = data.frame(date, color, quant, revenue)
```

df:

```
date    color quant revenue
04-01     Red     1      10
04-02    Blue     2      20
04-02  Yellow     1      10
04-03     Red     1      10
04-05    Blue     2      20
```

I want to complete all the missing date (start from `04-01` to `04-05`) for each color (`Red, Blue, Yellow`), filling `0` in column `quant` and `revenue`, output like this:

```
date    color quant revenue
04-01     Red     1      10
04-01    Blue     0       0
04-01  Yellow     0       0
04-02     Red     0       0
04-02    Blue     2      20
04-02  Yellow     1      10
04-03     Red     1      10
04-03    Blue     0       0
04-03  Yellow     0       0
04-04     Red     0       0
04-04    Blue     0       0
04-04  Yellow     0       0
04-05     Red     0       0
04-05    Blue     2      20
04-05  Yellow     0       0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `tidyverse` in `R` where we `separate` the 'date' into numeric 'day' 'year' columns, then use `complete` to expand the dataset and `unite` the 'day', 'year' to create the 'date' column

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
    separate(date, into = c('day', 'year'), convert = TRUE) %>% 
    complete(day, year = min(year):max(year), color,
               fill = list(quant = 0, revenue = 0)) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(day, year), funs(sprintf('%02d', .))) %>%
    unite(date, day, year, sep='-')
# A tibble: 15 x 4
#   date  color  quant revenue
#   <chr> <fct>  <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 04-01 Blue       0       0
# 2 04-01 Red        1      10
# 3 04-01 Yellow     0       0
# 4 04-02 Blue       2      20
# 5 04-02 Red        0       0
# 6 04-02 Yellow     1      10
# 7 04-03 Blue       0       0
# 8 04-03 Red        1      10
# 9 04-03 Yellow     0       0
#10 04-04 Blue       0       0
#11 04-04 Red        0       0
#12 04-04 Yellow     0       0
#13 04-05 Blue       2      20
#14 04-05 Red        0       0
#15 04-05 Yellow     0       0
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily with the `complete()` function in the `tidyr` package. For example

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(date=factor(date, levels=sprintf("04-%02d", 1:5))) %>% 
  complete(date, color, fill=list(quant=0, revenue=0))

#    date  color  quant revenue
#    <fct> <fct>  <dbl>   <dbl>
#  1 04-01 Blue       0       0
#  2 04-01 Red        1      10
#  3 04-01 Yellow     0       0
#  4 04-02 Blue       2      20
#  5 04-02 Red        0       0
#  6 04-02 Yellow     1      10
#  7 04-03 Blue       0       0
#  8 04-03 Red        1      10
#  9 04-03 Yellow     0       0
# 10 04-04 Blue       0       0
# 11 04-04 Red        0       0
# 12 04-04 Yellow     0       0
# 13 04-05 Blue       2      20
# 14 04-05 Red        0       0
# 15 04-05 Yellow     0       0
```

Comment: how could you also impute cases where `df$date == "04-04"`?

Comment: @ChrisHolbrook You can let know R about "missing" values by setting the proper levels for the factors involved. I've updated the answer to do a `mutate()` (from `dplyr`) to let R exactly which values to expand `date` to.

Answer (score 0):

A solution with base R that does not explicitly sequence by date:

```
df2 <- expand.grid(date = paste0("04-0", 1:5), 
                   color = c('Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow')) 
df2 <- merge(df2, df, by = c("date", "color"), all.x = TRUE) 
df2$quant[is.na(df2$quant)] <- 0 
df2$revenue[is.na(df2$revenue)] <- 0

df2
#    date  color quant revenue 
# 1  04-01   Blue     0       0 
# 2  04-01    Red     1      10 
# 3  04-01 Yellow     0       0 
# 4  04-02   Blue     2      20 
# 5  04-02    Red     0       0 
# 6  04-02 Yellow     1      10 
# 7  04-03   Blue     0       0 
# 8  04-03    Red     1      10 
# 9  04-03 Yellow     0       0 
# 10 04-04   Blue     0       0 
# 11 04-04    Red     0       0 
# 12 04-04 Yellow     0       0 
# 13 04-05   Blue     2      20 
# 14 04-05    Red     0       0 
# 15 04-05 Yellow     0       0
```